# Responsive CSS with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In my Rails app, I'm using `Twitter Bootstrap`. My footer is properly displayed on screens with landscape mode with width required enough.
Here is how it looks:
[image: Correctly displayed on browser on Mac]

But, on a browser on my Android Galaxy Note, it appears broken. The footer appears correct if I use the browser in landscape mode, but in the portrait mode it breaks. It looks like:
[image: Broken on browser on Android - small screen]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="muted credit" style="text-align: center" >

        &copy; 2013 <a href="http://www.example.com">WebsiteName.com</a> All Rights Reserved.   |   
        <a href="" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a>   |     
        <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', terms_of_service_path %>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the above is borrowed from [Example - sticky-footer](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html) :

```
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,
  #footer {
    height: 60px;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  }

  .container .credit {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
```

I don't know why does it not render it correctly. I am new to the Responsive CSS and I am learning. Please let me know what's wrong.

Comment: It looks like your footer doesn't fit in the available space on your Note.  So, how would you like your design to respond to the smaller space?

Comment: @KatieK: I'd like the Privacy Policy and Terms of Service to be displayed below the Copyright on another row.

Comment: Reason for down vote???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It renders perfectly normal. There is not enough space for the content to fit on one row, so it goes on a new row. If you want your links not to be separated on two rows like this and always fit on one row, try: `white-space: nowrap;` on the anchor tag, globally or on resolution of your choice.

Comment: I was also trying to increase the height of footer, but was unsuccessful. I tried to change the #footer height and accordingly set the #wrap margin value to negative. But, it didn't work.
I have no idea of how to fix this, I just used the above from an example on Bootstrap.

Comment: You can also try to put the copyright text in one div and the links in another. On bigger resolutions, you make them `display: inline;`, on smaller `display: block;`. That way they will be always on separate rows, regardless of their width.